# First API testing Framework with Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am setting up my own API testing framework but I am using [this guide](http://www.mwtestconsultancy.co.uk/automated-api-framework-part-1/) as a foundation.

In the guide it uses `rake` to run the tests from the rake file by using the default rake command.

The command runs all tests under the `spec` folder; however, I want to create a rake task I can run from the command line and just pass in which file under that folder I would like to run.

I.E. I want to run one script at a time from the command line, instead of running every file with the default rake command.

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

task :default => :spec

task :run do |file|

  :spec => file

   end
```

You can see the default rake command will run all tests under spec folder; however, I just want to pass in the file I want to run. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So your question is "how can my rake task accept an argument"? This should be easily googlable.

Comment: http://cobwwweb.com/4-ways-to-pass-arguments-to-a-rake-task

Comment: Why not just use `bin/rspec spec/foo`? The rspec command already takes a path as an argument. This can be a folder or an individual file.